# Loop User Input Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-input

I want to loop the input so I get 3 guesses, or 2 guesses and 1 clue:

```
if chosen == 1:
    print ("Your anagram is:", anagrameasy)
time.sleep(1)
easyguess = input ("Please input the answer in lower case, type clue for a clue")

if easyguess == answereasy:
    print ("correct")

     if easyguess == "clue":
        print (clueeasy)
        easyguess = input ("Please input the answer in lower case, type clue for a clue")

     elif easyguess != answereasy:
         print("try again")
```

Comment: 1. In what language you are trying to write? 2. Add your entire code. 3. Explain your problem better in order to make clearer what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.5.1 - Give user 3 invalid attempts then terminate pgm (Simple FOR loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897766/python-3-5-1-give-user-3-invalid-attempts-then-terminate-pgm-simple-for-loop)